# Person objects contain EnumSet. How to convert List<Person> to EnumMap<EnumSet.values, List<Person.name>> using aggregate functions / lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to learn **aggregate functions** and **lambdas** in Java. I have a class:

```
public class Person {
    public enum Privilege{
        PRIV1, PRIV2, PRIV3, PRIV4, PRIV4
    }
    private String name;
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;
...
}
```

and a list of objects of this class.
I want to convert it to `EnumMap<Privilege, List<String>>`
where List contains names of all people having certain privilege. I created a method to do this:

```
 public static Map<Privilege,List<String>> personsByPrivilege(List<Person> personList){
        Map<Privilege, List<String>> resultMap = new EnumMap(Privilege.class);
        Arrays.asList(Privilege.values())
                .stream()
                .forEach(p->resultMap.put(p,new ArrayList<String>()));
        for(Person p :personList){
            Set<Privilege> personsPrivileges = p.getPrivileges();
            for(Privilege pr : personsPrivileges){
                resultMap.get(pr).add(p.getName());
            }
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
```

How do I do it using **aggregate functions**?
I mean e.g. `personlist.stream().collect` style

Comment: What are "aggregate functions" for you ?

Comment: I mean e.g. ```personlist.stream().collect``` style

Comment: Honestly, `for (Person per : personList) { for (Privilege priv : per.getPrivileges()) {resultMap.computeIfAbsent(new ArrayList<>()).add(per.getName()); } }` is easier.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it’s `computeIfAbsent(priv, key -> new ArrayList<>())` but I agree, that’s the simplest solution. For the OP’s sake, using `forEach` instead of loops is possible, `personList.forEach(per -> per.getPrivileges().forEach(priv -> computeIfAbsent(priv, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(per.getName())));`

Comment: Yeah, missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the list of person -> list of privileges into pairs, then groupby by the privilege, and map with the name

```
public static Map<Person.Privilege, List<String>> personsByPrivilegeB(List<Person> personList) {
    return personList.stream()
            .flatMap(pers -> pers.getPrivileges().stream().map(priv -> new Object[]{priv, pers.getName()}))
            .collect(groupingBy(o -> (Person.Privilege) o[0], mapping(e -> (String) e[0], toList())));
}
```

Comment: The Problem is that every Input-Element (Person) may be in zero or more groups. You can't use just a ```groupingBy``` because that only allows you to assign every Input-Element to exactly one group

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Pair class and use the below code for achieving your goal

```
        return personList.stream().flatMap(p -> {
            String name = p.getName();
            return p.getPrivileges().stream()
                    .flatMap(priv -> Stream.of(new NamePriviledge(priv, name)));
        }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NamePriviledge::getPrivilege, Collectors.mapping(NamePriviledge::getName, Collectors.toList())));
    }

class NamePriviledge {
    private final Person.Privilege privilege;
    private final String name;

    public NamePriviledge(Person.Privilege privilege, String name) {
        this.privilege = privilege;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Person.Privilege getPrivilege() {
        return privilege;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NamePriviledge{" +
                "privilege=" + privilege +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```